# Node-container is unable to connect to MariaDB-container on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, mariadb, digital-ocean

I just set up an Ubuntu 21.04 Droplet on Digital Ocean and installed Docker according to [Docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/). I then installed `docker-compose` using `sudo apt install docker-compose`.

I then tried to launch my containers, a `linuxserver/mariadb` container called `mariadb` and a Node-app I've written myself which tries to connect to it. I was met with `ENOTFOUND 'mariadb'` errors and similiar errors. I tried to specify the IP-adress that lead to the MariaDB-container but no luck.

I could ping the MariaDB-container from bash (running `docker exec -it [my node container] /bin/sh` with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to uninstall (`sudo apt remove docker-compose`) and follow the official [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/).

After doing that my Node-container can finally resolve the hostname and connect to it.